# How to set foreground color of ListBox item

Tags: windows-phone-7, colors, listbox

I have a ListBox in a WP7 app page which I bind to a collection (List) of a custom object called Location.  In that object is a field called WMO and what I want to do when the ListBox loads is set the foregound color of whatever bound listbox item has that same value as my default value... but I just can't seem to get this working and nothing I've read or googled has helped.

I know the items in the list are bound to the datasource but I want to get to the physical representation of that item and change the foreground colour.... just can't work out how I do that so if anyone can help I'd appreciate it.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
    <ScrollViewer Height="615"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox Name="lbxSavedLocs" Height="615" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="470" SelectionChanged="lbxSavedLocs_SelectionChanged" Loaded="lbxSavedLocs_Loaded">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="380" Text="{Binding SiteName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Width="90" Text="{Binding WMO}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void lbxSavedLocs_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Populate the listbox from our saved locations.
    lbxSavedLocs.ItemsSource = gl.savedLocs.OrderBy(x => x.SiteName);

    foreach (Location itm in lbxSavedLocs.Items)
    {
        if (loc.WMO == gl.defaultWMO)
        {
          //GET AN "INVALID CAST" EXCEPTION HERE:
          ((ListBoxItem)itm).Foreground  = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        }
    }

    //Hopefully this produces a redraw of the ListBox.
    lbxSavedLocs.InvalidateArrange();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way....i think it works

The property you want to bind is `Foreground`, so

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
    <ScrollViewer Height="615" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox Name="lbxSavedLocs" Height="615" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="470" SelectionChanged="lbxSavedLocs_SelectionChanged" Loaded="lbxSavedLocs_Loaded">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="380" Text="{Binding SiteName}" Foreground="{binding forgroundColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Width="90" Text="{Binding WMO}" Foreground="{binding forgroundColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

In the program put up the apt condition where you populate your listbox to choose the right Forground using `foregroundColor`

Populate the list box using a class containin

```cs
class lisboxItem
{
    public string SiteName{get;set;}
    public string forgroundColor{get;set;}
    public string WMO{get;set;}
}
```

create a `List<listboxItem> items=new List<listboxItem>();`

and fill the list `items` in a loop where u give the condition you want.

after that
call 
`lbxSavedLocs.ItemSource=items`

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try, but is this something you've tested or is it just a guess?

Comment: my requirement was to change background of a/some particular listbox items dynamically!

Comment: i'm still looking for a code that will help me manipulate a single listboxitem, though!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Option1:

```
 ListBoxItem lbi1 = (ListBoxItem)(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0));
lbi1.Foreground= new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 45, 23, 45));
```

Option2:

```
ListBoxItem lbi2 = (ListBoxItem)(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.Items.SelectedItem));

 lbi2.Foreground= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, your first answer is the only one I can use as I don't have a SelectedItem in my loop as the default location is determined programatically and not from the user selecting one. But when I try the code below, "lbi1" is always null... any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to apply the same foreground colour to all items in the `ListBox` or to bind the foreground colour to a value in the data item, then the best approach is to modify the `ItemContainerStyle`. The `ItemContainerStyle` defines the visual wrapper around the contents of the `ItemTemplate` and by default uses a `ContentControl` that you can set or bind the `Foreground` property:

```
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                             To=".5"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                                             Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                            Foreground="#FFFF0000" 
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Background="Black"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Derek, but all I want to do is change the color of one line in a listbox in my code, based on a value in my bound object being equal to a default value set elsewhere. I appreciate that Setters are very powerful (and I use them elsewhere) but for what I want to do this does seem a little like smashing the proverbial nut with a hammer!  Definitely appreciate the input though. :-)

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can databind the color, too. So your data object would expose the color and return the default color in most circumstances and your custom color as required.